# INNER JOIN mysql boolean error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$results2=mysql_query("
SELECT * FROM searchengine
WHERE
   id IN (" . implode(',', $ids) . ")
   OR id IN (" . implode(',', $ids2) . ")
INNER JOIN keywords ON searchengine.id=keywords.id
ORDER BY
   (relevant-irrelevant) DESC,
   (rating/votes) DESC,
   report ASC,
   LENGTH(description) DESC,
   title ASC
LIMIT $page, $limit
");
```

Something in the code above doesn't function like i thought it will,the *While* loop returns the boolean error.

The code for implode functions are working fine.

My databases are *searchengine* and *keywords*

searchengine : id ,title,desc...

keywords : num,id,a,b

The A and B from id should be added to searchengine(based on same id) to make something like (id,title,desc,a,b...).Ask i you need more details.

NOTE:searchengine id is unique number,but keywords can have same id multiple times(one of the same ids is picked by A and B values and inserted as $ids1).

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "the while loop returns the boolean error". There is no while loop in your SQL Statement or the PHP(?) code

Comment: while($data2=mysql_fetch_array($results2))  didnt consider it to be of some importance but here it is,and error is this    Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Comment: Seems to be more of a PHP than a SQL problem then (or an interaction of the two)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Move the where clauses below the joins.
- Qualify the id with the table name. `searchengine.id`

---

```
SELECT *
FROM searchengine
INNER JOIN keywords ON searchengine.id=keywords.id
WHERE
   searchengine.id IN (" . implode(',', $ids) . ")
   OR searchengine.id IN (" . implode(',', $ids2) . ")
ORDER BY
   (relevant-irrelevant) DESC,
   (rating/votes) DESC,
   report ASC,
   LENGTH(description) DESC,
   title ASC
LIMIT $page, $limit
```

Comment: I added NOTE in my question,if i move WHERE on the end i belive that chaos happens in JOIN function cause of multiple id-s

Comment: That's why you need to qualify the id with the table `searchengine.id`

Comment: hm on second look it makes some more sense unfortunatley the boolean error is still present,il try add some more details.

Answer (score 0):

Your WHERE clause should come after the JOINs.

```
SELECT * 
    FROM searchengine 
        INNER JOIN keywords 
            ON searchengine.id=keywords.id 
    WHERE id IN (" . implode(',', $ids) . ") 
       OR id IN (" . implode(',', $ids2) . ")
    ORDER BY (relevant-irrelevant) DESC, (rating/votes) DESC, report ASC,  LENGTH(description) DESC, title ASC 
    LIMIT $page, $limit
```